# Angular 5 HTTP post internal server error not able to subscribe in component

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, http-post

I am calling this API with the angular HTTP.post method
http://10.108.11.239:8080/project/setRule

1. I am getting the response in the browser network tab but it shows an internal server error in the browser console tab.

Service method

public postSetup(data: Object, options?: RequestOptionsArgs) {

```
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    headers.append('USER', this.elem);
    let option = options ? options : new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.post(this.API_URL, data, option)
        .map((response: Response) => response.json())
        .catch((error: any) => {
           console.log(error) // able to see error here
            return Observable.throw(error);
        });
}
Component code
enter code here

 try {
               
                   this.myservice.postSetup(this.result)
                        .subscribe(
                        (data)  => {
                            this.message  =  data
                            console.log("response data");
                            console.log(data);
                            if (this.message !== null || this.message !== undefined){
                                this.display = true;
                            }
                               
                            else{
                                this.errorDisplay = true;
                                let res = JSON.parse( data._body);
                                console.log("submit scenario error try");// not able to print message here
                                console.log(res)
                            }
                              

                        }
                        )
                         

                }
                catch (err) {
                   
                    this.errorDisplay = true;
                    let res = JSON.parse(err._body);
                    console.log("submit scenario error");// not able to print here
                    console.log(res)
                    this.sError = res['errorMsg'];
                    this.errorDesc = res['errorDesc'];
                }
```

Note: Control is not coming in subscribe function, however, I am able to subscribe error when calling other API using HTTP.get. kindly suggest. what is missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The subscribe function also can take an object like this.

```js
this.someService.makeRequest(someData).subscribe({ next: (successData) => {
// Here only if is all went well
}, error: (e)  => {
// Here only is something went wrong
}})
```

If a error was throw inside an observable, `error` will be called.